# Deleting and appending contents to file?

Tags: java, android, android-file

I am reading some data from web and writing it to a file. Simultaneously I am reading data from file also. Means from one end writing to file and another end reading from same file. So my file size is increasing and crossing its limits.

So I have decided to delete data after the reading operation. So I can keep my file size constant. I have search for Android API and in Google, found nothing. If any one know, please help me.

Here is my writing code :

```
for(String url : myURLs) {
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                try {
                    HttpResponse responce = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    StatusLine statusLine = responce.getStatusLine();
                    if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == 200) {
                        HttpEntity entity = responce.getEntity();
                        entity.writeTo(fos);
                        entity.consumeContent();
                        fos.flush();
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: If you're deleting the data you just read from the file, why not just create a new file for the data being written from the internet?

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) - I think we have one here. Rather than discussing a weird solution to your problem, please provide a bit more background about your problem and let us suggest better solutions. Why is this file being used at all?

Comment: Simply saying I am using this file as a buffer.